# How to have a cron script that should call chef-databag to get username and password every time it runs?

Tags: python, authentication, chef-infra, databags

I have a cronjob which executes a python script. python script takes two parameter username and pass.

for example :  execute.py vijay hTbY87

Requirement is to take this username and pass from dataBag i have in chef.
My instance where i need to run this cronjob is in AWS.

Is there a way to have such a cronjob ?

Comment: The purpose of databag mainly is to store contents and later use in recipes/knife commands. I think for your purpose you can decode password inside your Python script instead of passing it plain text?

Comment: Yes thought of the same but pychef is not currently installed on the instance.

Answer (score 2):

So assuming you're using the built-in `cron` resource (you might want to use the `cron_d` resource instead, there are some subtle differences), it's all just writing the Ruby code you want:

```
params = data_bag_item('bagname', 'itemname')

cron 'myscript' do
  command "python /path/to/execute.py #{params['user']} #{params['password']}"
  # Other properties here to set the schedule.
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a cronrun.sh file that contains the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

crontab <<EOF
*/30 * * * * /path/to/execute.py vijay hTbY87 > /path/to/logs/output.log 2>&1
EOF
```

This would execute every 30 minutes and will pipe the output (or Error message) to a logs directory. To search for another time interval, Google `crontab.guru every ___ minutes` or hours or days or whatever you want.

Make sure that you type `chmod +x cronrush.sh` so that the file becomes executable.

Comment: Seems like you misunderstood the question. I want to get vijay hTbY87 from the data bag.

Comment: This is not related to Chef, though it's correct as a general answer for Unix.